# How do I extract two lists from a tuple containing two lists before I zip them? (using OCaml)

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

If I have an input of a tuple containing two lists of integers of the same length, and I want my output to be a list of these two lists zipped, then how do I first extract these two lists from the tuple? For example, if my input is twolists= ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]), then I want my output to be [(1,4); (2,5); (3,6)]. How do I first separate the tuple into (for example) l1= [1;2;3], and l2= [4;5;6]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to get the components of a tuple. For example, this function takes a tuple of two ints and returns their sum:

```
let add_uncurried tuple =
    let (a, b) = tuple in a + b
```

To put it another way, you can write `let (a, b) = tuple in ...` to get the components of the tuple under the names `a` and `b`.

Comment: You can even already pattern match in the function definition as in `let add_uncurried (a, b) = a + b`. This also shows more clearly that the function expects a tuple.